# Validating empty xml by xsd in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following simple xsd schema:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="MyUrl" type="xsd:anyURI"/>
</xsd:schema>'
```

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 and I want to validate my variable against this schema. It works, but variable x got validated even if it's empty or whitespace, however empty xml isn't valid against this schema.

Why I got these results?

TSQL code:

```
CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION dbo.xsdTest AS
N'<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="MyUrl" type="xsd:anyURI"/>
</xsd:schema>'
GO

DECLARE @x XML(dbo.xsdTest)
SET @x = ' ' --no error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the [XML data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187339.aspx) accepts XML fragments as valid XML.

> The XML data can contain multiple zero or more elements at the top
>   level.

You can specify that the XML must be a valid XML document like this.

```
declare @x xml(document dbo.xsdTest)
set @x = '' -- error here
```